# insert milliseconds from csv into psql

Tags: postgresql, csv

here is how I created the table:

```
create table test(date date, time timestamp, sym varchar, sym_suffix varchar, size integer, price decimal);
```

my code to copy from csv to teh table

```
copy test FROM 'e791acd30df31154.csv' WITH DELIMITER  ',' CSV HEADER;
```

the error i get is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "8:00:02.051"
CONTEXT:  COPY penny, line 2, column time: "8:00:02.051"
```

how can i get postgres to save the milliseconds?

Comment: Your column should be of `time` type (`timestamp` has date part).

Comment: That did the trick thanks